# How to render list of instances without losing state/recreating component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Experimenting with making my own React router with some animations. Hit a brick wall.

I'm rendering a stack of screens.
The stack can be popped or pushed.

My problem is that when the stack changes the state is lost and the constructor is called again destroying the previous state (making the stack useless) . 
How would I do this?

**Create the screen** (After this we push to the stack which is on the state)

```
/**
 * Create a new React.Element as a screen and pass props.
 */
createNewScreen = (screenName: string, props: ?any = {}): any => {

    // Props is not an object.
    if (typeof props !== 'object') {
        Logger.error(`Passed props to screen name ${screenName} wasn't an object or undefined. Will error next screens.`);
        return;
    }

    let propsUnlocked = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(props));

    // Add unique screen it.
    const uniqueScreenKey = this.generateRandomUniqueID();
    propsUnlocked.key = uniqueScreenKey;
    propsUnlocked.screenId = uniqueScreenKey;
    propsUnlocked.navKing = this;
    propsUnlocked.screenName = screenName;

    // Find the original screen to copy from.
    // This just copies the 'type'
    // $FlowFixMe
    return React.createElement(this.findScreenNameComponent(screenName).type, propsUnlocked);
}
```

**Render the screens**

```
render() {
    return ( <View 
            {...this.props} 
            onLayout={(event) => this.onLayout(event)} 
            pointerEvents={this.state.isAnimating ? 'none' : undefined} 
            >
        { this.renderStackOfScreens() }
    </View>);
};

renderStackOfScreens() {
    // Render screens.
    return this.state.stackOfScreens
    .map((eachScreen, index) => {

        // Render second last screen IF animating. Basically because we have a screen animating over the top.
        if (index === this.state.stackOfScreens.length - 2 && this.state.isAnimating) {
            return (
                <Animated.View 
                    key={eachScreen.props.screenId + '_parent'} 
                    style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0 }}>
                    { eachScreen }
                </Animated.View>
            );
        }

        // Render last screen which is animated.
        if (index === this.state.stackOfScreens.length - 1) {
            return (
                <Animated.View 
                    key={eachScreen.props.screenId + '_parent'}
                    style={this.getOffset(this.state.animatedScreenOffset)}>
                    { eachScreen }
                </Animated.View>
            );
        }
    })
    // Remove the undefined values.
    .filter((eachScreen) => !!eachScreen);
}
```

Can see the full example here
https://pastebin.com/BbazipKt

Screen types are passed in as unique children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once a component is unmounted, its state is gone forever. You might think "well I have a variable reference to the component so even though it's unmounted it still keeps its state, right?" Nope, React doesn't work that way. Unmounting a component is tantamount to destroying it. Even if you remount the "same" component again, as far as React is concerned it's a brand new component, with a brand new constructor call, mounting lifecycle, etc. So you need to abandon your approach of keeping the React components themselves in arrays as the history stack.

Frustrating, I know. Believe me, I've run into the same problem.

The solution is to pull out your View/Screen states from the components themselves and lift them into a parent. In essence, you're keeping the states in an array in the parent, and then passing them as props into the Views/Screens themselves. This might *seem* like a counter-intuitive, "non-Reactful" way of doing things, but [it actually is in line with how React is intended to be used](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). State should generally be "lifted up" to the level of the closest common ancestor that all components will need access to it from. In this case, you need access to your state at a level *above* the Views/Screens themselves, so you need to lift it up.

Here's some pseudocode to illustrate.

Right now, your app seems to be structured sorta like this:

```
// App state
state: {
  // stackOfScreens is React components.
  // This won't work if you're trying to persist state!
  stackOfScreens: [
    <Screen />,
    <Screen />,
    <Screen />
  ]
}

// App render function
render() {
  return <div>
    {
      this.state.stackOfScreens.map((ea, i) => {
        return <View key={i} >{ea}</View>
      }
    }
  </div>
}
```

Instead it should be like this:

```
// App state
state: {
  // stackOfScreens is an array of JS objects.
  // They hold your state in a place that is persistent,
  // so you can modify it and render the resulting
  // React components arbitrarily
  stackOfScreens: [
    {
      name: "screen#1",
      foo: "Some sort of 'screen' state",
      bar: "More state,
      baz: "etc."
    },
    {
      name: "screen#2",
      foo: "Some sort of 'screen' state",
      bar: "More state,
      baz: "etc."
    },
    {
      name: "screen#3",
      foo: "Some sort of 'screen' state",
      bar: "More state,
      baz: "etc."
    },
  ]
}

// App render function
render() {
  return <div>
    {
      this.state.stackOfScreens.map((ea, i) => {
        return <View key={i} >
          <Screen stateData={ea} callback={this.screenCallback} />
        </View>
      }
    }
  </div>
}
```

Notice the addition of a `callback` prop on the Screen components that you're rendering. Thats so that you can trigger changes to the rendered Screen "state" (which is actually tracked in the parent) from within the Screen.

Comment: At the moment each screen is a 'type' of component, how would I render this? 
I've pushed my code example here: 
https://pastebin.com/BbazipKt

Comment: Also, rendering all the previous screens will take a performance hit? (I'm doing this on mobile hehe)

Comment: @OliverDixon It's just pseudocode, you wouldn't necessarily render all the screens, maybe just the current one and one being transitioned out. Look into ReactCSSTransitionGroup for a good way to animate mounting/unmounting components. For the type, you could keep the component "type" as a property in the state object for each screen and use that to determine which component type to render it with.

Comment: I can't save the state unless I render the screen. So it looks like it's impossible to do screens only doing it the 'react' way on mobile. (Constructor is always called more than once, not good)